# 'Label' in assembly language - opcode

Tags: assembly, label, opcode, 8085

I am currently learning to program in the 8085 microprocessor. Take a look at the program below:

```
LXI H, 2050
MOV B, M
INX H
MOV C, M
MVI A 00H
TOP: ADD B
DCR C
JNZ TOP
INX H
MOV M, A
HLT
```

This program multiplies two 8-bit numbers in the 8085 microprocessor.
I know 'LXI H, 2050' has the hexadecimal operation code (opcode) '21, 50, 20'. In place of 'TOP: ADD B' and 'JNZ TOP', what opcode should I write, and what is the opcode for statements with labels in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no opcode for a label itself.  The assembler translates labels into addresses when you reference them from other places.

`TOP: ADD B` will be translated simply to `80`, just as if the label wasn't there.  The label address is the address where the `80` goes, the current position in the output for that line.

If, for example, this location is at address 1000H, `JNZ TOP` translates to `C2 00 10`.

Comment: So how do I find out the address of the ADD B instruction? I'm confused

Comment: By compiling the program. Normally a compiler will do two passes: once to figure out what the instructions are and how big everything is; then it figures out where all the labels' targets are, and fix the addresses accordingly. You can do the same thing manually. `TOP:` is not part of the machine code: it is just a bookmark for the compiler to know what address to put in when it translates `JNZ TOP`.

Comment: Since the compiler fixes the addresses, I need not enter the address of the label?

Comment: I believe I already answered: if the instruction labeled as `TOP:` lands at `1000H`, then the code for `JNZ TOP` is equal to `JNZ 1000H`: `C2 00 10`. You can see where the instruction ends by counting instruction sizes, and knowing where the code will start. `LXI H` takes 3 bytes, `MOV B, M` is 1, just like the next two instructions, and `MVI A` is 2. This means `TOP` will be 8 bytes after the address of the first instruction.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I got it cleared now